# C# roll dice minimize number of dice every round

Tags: c#

i need help please anyone. I did an array and a loop that stops when a number is identified. Its not suppose to happen that way.

It rolls 5 dice but when a number is identified, it should lessen the number of dice for the next round. It plays 3 rounds altogether until that number is identified. It should identify 6 then 5 .... only three round is given.

The problem is i want it to display everything in the array before and tell that the number exist.

```
public dice()
        {
            int Round = 0;
            int Dice = 5;
            int Six = 6;
            int Five = 5;
            int Four = 4;
            int NOW = Six;


                do
                {                      
                    for (int i = 0; i < Dice; i++)
                    {
                        {
                            rolldice();
                            Console.Write("{0} ", die.Face());
                        }
                    }
                        if (die.Face() == NOW)
                        {

                            Dice--;
                            Console.WriteLine("You got SIX");
                            Now = Five;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("ENTER to roll {0} dice", Dice);             
                        Round++;
                }
                while (Round < 3);
```

Should display:

4 3 2 4 6
you got SIX

ENTER to roll 4 dice

1 1 5 3
you got FIVE

ENTER to roll 3 dice

Comment: Why have three ifs that checks the same thing? Just set Now = Now - 1 in the first if.

Answer (score 2):

You're rolling *all* the dice, and then just checking the last one - all your tests are outside the loop.

That's just the first step in making this work though - there are various other issues with it. In particular, I would suggest having just *one* condition, not three... you only want to see whether any of the dice has the *current* value you're looking for.

I'll leave it at that for the moment, so you can learn by thinking it through for yourself - but when you're happy with what you've got, you can always ask for hints as to how to improve the solution too.

Comment: TQ Jon skeet ... yes, it does check only the last value.. will try to find solution for it.